# AVPlayer & MPMoviePlayerController Can't Be Muted --- Forcing Background Audio Dim

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

My app plays a video and occasionally has verbal queues. When there is nothing being said by the app, I want the audio (in the background say from Spotify or iTunes) to come back to full volume. When there is audio I want the audio to dim.

I have set the audio session to `DuckOthers`.

The problem is, whenever I restore the background audio:

```
class func restoreBackgroundAudio()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    } catch _ {
        print("ERROR restoring background audio")
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> [0x1a03a9000] AVAudioSession.mm:697: -[AVAudioSession
>   setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has
>   running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating
>   the audio session.

The problem is that the video file that is playing seems to have an audio that I cannot mute.

I have tried the following:

1. I removed the audio track from the video and tried playing it in an MPMoviePlayerController

   ```
   _movie                                = MPMoviePlayerController()
   _movie.controlStyle                   = MPMovieControlStyle.None
   _movie.view.frame                     = _movieView.frame
   _movie.repeatMode                     = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
   _movie.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   _movie.contentURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/\(videoName)"))
    _movie.play()
   ```

Every time the movie plays its loop it forces the background audio to dim even though I am  not setting `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)`

2. Making my own AVPlayerItem and AVPlayer, and manually muting the audio tracks inside the AVPlayerItem as well as setting the AVPlayer to muted:

   ```
       var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: _movieURL)
       var audioTracks = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
       // Set the volume of ANY potential audio track to 0
       var allAudioParams:[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters] = []
       for track:AVAssetTrack in audioTracks
       {
           var audioInputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters()
           audioInputParams.setVolume(0.0, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
           audioInputParams.trackID = track.trackID
           allAudioParams.append(audioInputParams)
       }

       var muteTrack = AVMutableAudioMix()
       muteTrack.inputParameters = allAudioParams

       var item:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: _movieURL)
       // Assign the muted audio track
       item.audioMix = muteTrack

       _avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
       // Also set the AVPlayer to be muted
       _avPlayer.muted = true
       let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: _avPlayer)
       playerLayer.frame = _movie.view.frame
       layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

       _avPlayer.play() // ALWAYS DIMS BACKGROUND AUDIO!
   ```

Again, once the video loops it always dims the background audio. I tried hacking it and doing a `restoreBackgroundAudio()` call right after I hit the play button, but I get a bad fade in and out and in and out effect like its trying to restore the background audio but the active video player is forcing the dim as an override.

If you have any suggestions on what else I can do to either actually mute a video thats playing or play a video that doesnt dim the background I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you not simply set the _avPlayer.volume = 0; that works.

Comment: That has no effect. Even at volume 0 background audio dims

Comment: You know, to solve this issue I would go back to basics. Implement each of these thing separately and set your volume controls; and then try merging them again.

Comment: I've tried all of that, I am posting this question in hopes of a more technical solution someone might have.

Comment: MPVolumeView might be the answer: I frequently find myself not actually logging an SO question, cause as I typing it in; I alway check the suggestions it makes before press post; I do now anyway.  Any look at this one; I know its old but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095644/mute-audio-tracks-of-live-streams-using-avplayer?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but thats about file streaming. Also their solution, and one linked to still does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the main problem is, that when AVPlayer plays video, even if it is muted, it will stop background music from other apps.

It is the default behaviour of the AVAudioSession manager. What I do not understand is why AVAudioSession manager "kills" background music even if there is no sound output in action (AVPlayer is muted). This behaviour is also problem for me.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272536/901508) is what I suggest to do in this case.

And [here](https://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/133423436921/controlling-audio-output-on-ios-with) you can read about AVAudioSession management.

Comment: Yes I had tried that. But you are not meant to change the audio session type, its a 'set and forget' design. When you try to do that (and I did) you get this random long dim followed by undim effect. The framework spazzes out and does not like having its session changed on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use this to allow mixing of your app audio with other apps audio:

```
NSError *silentSwitcherror = nil;
BOOL silentSwitchSuccess = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&silentSwitcherror];
if (silentSwitchSuccess) {
//insert video player code here to play video
}
else
{
//insert video player code here to play video
}
```